# Can I get my Origin profile link?

Tags: origin

I'm forming a list of links of where people can add me on, I was able to obtain tens of profile links, but I wasn't able to get a link for my origin.

Is there way I can link people to my origin profile? I don't want to just put up my username.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered this question just searching for the same as the OP looking for an way to get my [origin](/questions/tagged/origin) profile's URL address. So I posted for those trying to find the same...

**First up:** All information online (even EA/Origin's own AnswerHQ page) just states that it is not possible to obtain a link to your profile URL address from the EA or Origin web site (for some reason they purposely obscure it). There are a couple of places saying that it *might* be obtainable from the Origin Game Client. Well, I looked pretty thoroughly through the client and I could not find it... If it is in there somewhere, it is pretty well hidden! So I'm pretty sure it is not there either.

However, I did discover a way to reveal it via the Origin web site - *with a little trick*.

**Solution:**

1. While logged in to the `origin.com` web site, hover over your `profile name` in the bottom left corner of the page, and select `View My Profile` from the pop up menu. This will show your profile, but with a frustratingly generic web address in your browser's address bar!
2. Now that your profile is showing, click the `Friends` tab on your profile page to reveal other players you have befriended (it doesn't matter if your friends list is empty), and select the words `Find friends` on the page. Now in the search query box, instead of searching for someone else, search for *your profile name*.
3. Find yourself in the list of others that have similar profile names as you. (Hopefully you have a profile pic to make it easier on yourself.)
4. Select `View Profile` when you hover over your profile pic, this will send the browser back to your profile page again, but now, tada! Your browser's address bar will be showing your full profile URL!
5. Select and copy everything of the URL in the browser address bar, except the word "achievements" at the end of it - if you want the exact link - and you now have a copy of your unique profile URL to paste elsewhere, for whatever you need!

Answer (score 0):

Not through a web browser, but it [should be possible](http://www.steamgifts.com/discussion/Jj8Gg/is-it-possible-to-get-a-link-for-origin-user-profiles) through the Origin desktop client